# Xcode 11 Beta 5 Debugger nil nonsense?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, beta

Trying to create a directory under the Application Support directory on iOS for my app, but I'm getting weird results in the debugger. As you can see below, the debugger says that seedDir is nil, yet line 19 succeeded in printing out the path of seedDir to the console!?

[image: Xcode Beta 5 Debugger nonsense]

Comment: @CodeBender that's a compile time warning not a runtime warning. You can set a compiler flag that will get the compiler to measure how long it takes to type check code you write that's, for example, using generics, where it'll have to figure out the concrete types involved, and warns you if you've been writing overly complex code. I get the warning because I'm on a 2013 MBA, well that's what I tell myself :-)

Comment: Note the application support directory does not exist by default. You have to create it. The usual pattern is `try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)` (note the `create` value of `true`). See [`url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407693-url).

Comment: @Rob that's exactly what my computed property `public var applicationSupportDirectory: URL` is doing.